# Manyears 1.1.2 sources, compile cmake file

Tags: cmake

I would like to compile the cmake file from Manyears 1.1.2 sources, but I got the errors as below:

```
WARNING : manyears GUI will not be compiled because Qt4 not found
-- Buiding ManyEarsLib Library...
CMake Error at dsplib/CMakeLists.txt:75 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
-- Buiding RTAudio Library...
CMake Error at example/CMakeLists.txt:22 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with illegal arguments, maybe missing a
  PROPERTIES specifier?
```

And the original program has been written as below:

```
target_link_libraries(ManyEarsLib )
set_target_properties(ManyEarsLib PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${MANYEARS_LINK_FLAGS} OUTPUT_NAME man-years)

add_executable(manyears_console manyears_console.c)
set_target_properties(manyears_console PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${MANYEARS_LINK_FLAGS})
target_link_libraries(manyears_console ManyEarsLib -lm)
```

Could somebody tell me what is the problem and how to risolve it?

Thanks a lot.
Lun

Answer (score 0):

Command [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html) may only set **single-value** properties.

But you attempt to set property *LINK_FLAGS*, which is generally **multi-value** (a **list**), but in your case it is simply empty. That is why first invocation detects incorrect number of arguments (it should be even), and the second invocation detects insufficient number of arguments (is should be 4 at least).

For set **multi-value** properties or for clear them use command [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html):

```
# Multi-value (or empty) property
set_property(TARGET ManyEarsLib PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS ${MANYEARS_LINK_FLAGS})
# Single-value property
set_target_properties(ManyEarsLib PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME man-years)
# Multi-value (or empty) property again
set_property(TARGET manyears_console PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS ${MANYEARS_LINK_FLAGS})
```

or even

```
# Multi-value (or empty) property for several targets
set_property(TARGET ManyEarsLib manyears_console PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS ${MANYEARS_LINK_FLAGS})
# Single-value property for single target
set_target_properties(ManyEarsLib PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME man-years)
```